# Is there a way to execute a file and one line of program in perl?

Tags: perl, org-mode, org-babel

I want to execute some code before execution(redirect stderr to stdout).

```
perl -e "BEGIN {open STDERR, '>&STDOUT'}" perl.pl
```

But when there is -e, no file will be executed. I know `$Config{sitelib}/sitecustomize.pl` can pre-execute some code, and -f option can disable it. But this way is inflexible.  In most cases, I do not need to add extra code. I don't want to add -f every time.

I cannot use shell to redirect. I want to set `org-babel-perl-command` in emacs org mode so that stdout and stderr can be printed in the same way, instead of opening another window to print stderr. `org-babel-perl-command` should be like `perl`.

For example, `org-babel-python-command` can be set to `python -i -c "import sys; sys.stderr = sys.stdout"`.

Comment: I made a mistake, it should be stdout.

Comment: Is there something wrong with `perl perl.pl 2>&1` ?

Comment: @jhnc I can't, because I do not use it in a shell script, but a emacs org-mode variable(org-babel-perl-command).

Comment: Can you use `sh -c 'perl "$1" 2>&1' dummy perl.pl`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bash
perl -e'
   open( STDERR, ">&STDOUT" );
   do( shift( @ARGV ) );
' perl.pl
```

(Error handling needed.)

For the case in question, the following would suffice:

```bash
perl perl.pl 2>&1
```

Maybe even

```bash
./perl.pl 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just make a wrapper for perl. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec perl "$@" 2>&1
```

Then make it executable and use instead of perl in your `org-babel-perl-command`. Ensure it can be found in your `PATH` or use full location.